# Regex and Perforce commands

Tags: regex, perforce

Is it possible to embed regex expressions into perforce commands?

So for an example I know the files name, but I only wish to get it from locations that end in a "v" or a "/". So something like:

`p4 files //depot/.../LOCATION(v|/).../file.txt@label`

However it doesn't appear the perforce likes that, so am I limited to doing something like:

`p4 files //depot/.../file.txt@label | ack "/LOCATION(v|/)"`

Or is there a way of including regex expressions in perforce commands? Or even an or expression for characters?

**Further Example:**

So a depot location could look like:

```
 1. //depot/folder1/folder2/LOCATIONv9/folder3/file.txt
 2. //depot/folder1/folder2/LOCATION/folder3/file.txt
 3. //depot/folder1/folder2/LOCATIONINVALID/folder3/file.txt
```

So from the examples above i'd be looking to just return locations 1 and 2, and ignore location 3.

Comment: Can you expand you example and write some example paths? There are few wildcards that you can use in perforce paths but they are not support any logical OR.

Answer (score 2):

The `p4 grep` command supports regex expressions to search within file content, but regexes aren't a valid way to specify file paths or revisions in the general case.

You can use multiple recursive wildcards though, e.g.:

```
p4 files //depot/.../LOCATION.../file.txt@label
```